# how to find the y-coordinate of the center of a circle with this information?

Tags: geometry

[image]

sorry for the really basic question. i am looking at this old SAT question. what i am thinking is to plug in the coordinates of x and y into the equation of a circle for each coordinate and then solve a system of equations but that seems too tedious for an SAT question.is there any relationship between a chord and the origin? thanks for the help

Comment: Look at the triangle with vertices $(h,k)$, $(4,0)$ and $C$, where $C$ is the point of intersection of the $x$-axis and the perpendicular to the $x$-axis passing through $(h,k)$.

Comment: Pythagoras. The $X$-coordinate is the mid-point of the two points given.

Comment: First find $h$. Not too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is apply the Pythagorean theorem.

You know the horizontal distance between the origin and any of the two intersections (it is $(20-4)/2 = 8$).

Once you know that, you can build a right triangle between one of the intersections (say $(4,0)$), the origin and $(4,k)$ and solve for $k$ in the following formula

$$k^2 + 8^2 = 10^2$$

Comment: Why not? There exists a point directly above $(4,0)$ which makes the $(4,0)-(h,k)-(4,k)$ triangle right. The side $(4,k)-(4,0)$ is surely perpendicular to the x-axis.

Comment: True (+1) $\quad\quad$

Answer (score 0):

The equation of this circle is:
$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=100.$$ First Observe that $h,k>0$.Note that this circle passes through  the point $(4,0)$ thus: $(4-h)^2+k^2=100$ also it passes through $(20,0)$ therefore $(20-h)^2+k^2=100$. Can you take it from here.

Comment: yeah that's what i said i was thinking originally in my question. but i wanted a simpler way of doing it